# Uploading large files from android app to server using Perl

Tags: java, android, upload

I need to upload videos from my android app to my website.

I use an async task and a method (included here below) to send the video, but I do not know how to set up the Perl scrip on my site that would interact with the app.

By now any test perl script (with any chmod combination) I use as a targetURL returns:
03-30 17:09:06.771: I/Server Response Code(21092): 403
03-30 17:09:06.771: I/Server Response Message(21092): Forbidden

I would greatly appreciate any general direction on how to make the Perl script and what permissions to give it.
I looked around the Internet for example, but there are few and in PHP, and I need it in Perl.

```
        public String sendFileToServer(String filename, String targetUrl) {
        String response = "error";

        Log.e("Video filename", filename);
        Log.e("url", targetUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        // DataInputStream inputStream = null;

        String pathToOurFile = filename;
        String urlServer = targetUrl;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH:mm:ss");

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    pathToOurFile));

            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            String connstr = null;
            connstr = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                    + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd;
            Log.i("Connstr", connstr);

            outputStream.writeBytes(connstr);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            Log.e("Video length", bytesAvailable + "");
            try {
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    try {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        response = "outofmemoryerror";
                        return response;
                    }
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "error";
                return response;
            }
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                    + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
            Log.i("Server Response Code ", "" + serverResponseCode);
            Log.i("Server Response Message", serverResponseMessage);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                response = "true";
            }

            String CDate = null;
            Date serverTime = new Date(connection.getDate());
            try {
                CDate = df.format(serverTime);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Date Exception", e.getMessage() + " Parse Exception");
            }
            Log.i("Server Response Time", CDate + "");

            filename = CDate
                    + filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("."),
                            filename.length());
            Log.i("File Name in Server : ", filename);

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            outputStream = null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Exception handling
            response = "error";
            Log.e("Send file Exception", ex.getMessage() + "");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Here is a example of  server side code is written in Php. What it should be in Perl?

```
    <?php
// Where the file is going to be placed
$target_path = "uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " .$target_path;
}
?>
```

Comment: The code above isn't Perl, is it? How can anyone help you with a perl script you aren't showing? The platform sending the file shouldn't matter - you should be able to test it with a simple curl call.

Comment: Did you mean to tag this with Java? I have done it for you anyway. Please help us to help you by posting all relevant code

Comment: This code is in Java and is in my android app.

Comment: I added example of the server side code in PHP. I need help on this code written in Perl.